# Sync Internet calendar with office 365 Calendar for all devices (smartphone)

Tags: outlook, office365, icalendar

I have an Internet calendar (.ics) that I will sync with my office 365 account.
In the outlook desktop app, I can easily add an internet calendar with username and password, and I have the ability to edit the sync interval (1 min) - working fine.
My problem is now, I can't see this calendar on my Smartphone.
Adding this calendar in outlook.com (also in the cloud) doesn't work because MS only allows public ics calendar (why MS why?).
I can copy the internet calendar in outlook desktop app to my "own calendar" but then I have only a snapshot not the sync internet calendar...

Is there a solution for my problem? I can't publish the calendar without password and username...

Comment: SO is mainly for coding related questions, so if I understand your question correctly it is pretty much off topic. If it's not, please add some detail, like error messages or your code snippets to your question.

Comment: sorry you are right - is off topic problem not an coding problem.

Comment: No problem! You can look the stuff you can ask here up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). :)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud-based syncing services: Web apps like Dropbox, Apple's iCloud, and Microsoft's Live Mesh synchronize folder(s) among your devices while saving copies of the shared folders online. Changes made to files in that folder from one device automatically get updated on the others. You can also enable file sharing, use a mobile phone to access the files, and in some apps, open the files on the website.
Desktop applications: If you're not comfortable with your files being stored online, you can install software that synchronizes files locally or over a private network. Shareware and freeware file-syncing applications include GoodSync, Microsoft's SyncToy, and SyncBack. Besides offering more robust options for file syncing (keeping multiple versions of replaced files, setting a schedule for syncing compressing or encrypting files, etc.), these programs also typically allow you to sync with external drives, FTP sites, and servers. Take a closer look at these and other syncing apps in a roundup of the best file syncing apps.

[More information here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-sync-your-data-across-multiple-devices-2378018)

Also specifically here is a video explain how to share colander across all your devices [click here to watch it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H8uJT5kqyY)

Comment: I know Cloud-based Syncing service like drop box, but i dont want to share a file. I have a Link like This: https://example.com/sharedCalender/xyz.ics | dont want to download the file every day and sync with all devices...

Comment: try this it will work for you ,
https://www.zoho.com/mail/

if all is ok go ahead and let me know I will edit my answer and adjust it ...

Comment: How will this help me? zoho is just an email provider.. ?

Comment: well , it does not matter , you just need to make one account on your domain to make everything sync into it and you gotta share this synced account for those who you would like them to see the calender

Comment: ok other question. Is there an Addin for Outlook Desktop-Client which can sync my added internet calendar with my own calendar? I found caldav synchronizer, but unfortunately doesnt work with my "stupid" internet calendar :)